# How can I check what servers I can ssh into?

Tags: linux, ssh

I've inherited a Linux server that had some ssh privileges setup on it to connect to other Linux servers. The thing is there is no documentation on where those privileges are stored and they are not setup consistently across all machines.

Is there a way to check what accounts and servers I can log into without a password on an existing machine?

Comment: The privileges for connecting to another server are maintained on that other server.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lurker says, the permissions are maintained on the server.  You need look through the /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts and ~/.ssh/known_hosts files on all your servers to find out which hosts can connect.